# How to disable dates after today date in DatePickerDialog Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker, android-datepicker, datepickerdialog

I want to disable all **Next(after)** dates from **today** date in DatePickerDialog.

I am using below code to create DatePickerDialog:

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

 //OnDateSetListener
 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener myDateListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker arg0, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        calendar.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        String currentDate = date_format.format(calendar.getTime());
        ...
    }
};
 //Create DatePickerDialog here
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    if (id == 999) {
        DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), myDateListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);

        return dpDialog;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Please suggest what I have to do for disable all previous date in datepicker dialog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Disable future dates in Android date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970963/how-to-disable-future-dates-in-android-date-picker)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just pass current date in `setMaxDate()` of `DatePickerDialog`.

```
DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), myDateListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

or

```
dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```