# I want to disable the dates after today date in the DatePickerDialog

Tags: android

```
int mMonth = 0, mDay = 0, mYear = 0;
            DatePickerDialog mDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(activity_registrationactivityy.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker datepicker, int selectedyear, int selectedmonth, int selectedday) {
                    Calendar mcurrentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int mYear = selectedyear;
                    int mMonth = selectedmonth;
                    int mDay = selectedday;

                    DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getApplicationContext(), mDatePicker, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                    dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(mcurrentDate.getTimeInMillis());


                    et_birthdate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mDay).append("/").append(mMonth + 1).append("/").append(mYear));

                    //takes current date
                }
            }, m`enter code here`Year, mMonth, mDay);
            mDatePicker.setTitle("Select date");
            mDatePicker.show();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Disable future dates in Android date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970963/how-to-disable-future-dates-in-android-date-picker)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method `setMaxDate(long maxDate)`

To disable future dates use the following:

```
dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), myDateListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```